# Getting 'A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization' exception

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

This question is related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906356/how-to-solve-a-a-reference-tracked-object-changed-reference-during-deserializat

Since the above post has been closed, I created a new one that includes the test code to reproduce the problem and the exception stack trace.

What is going here, why the error? Also I am not clear on the tag for the ProtoInclude. If the tag is equal to a ProtoMember then I get an exception about a duplicate field number. So, I usually set it to max(ProtoMember tag) + 1. Is this what the tool expects?

I run this example with the latest code from svn (downloaded today).

Thanks

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(6, typeof(B))]
public class A
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public int Property1 { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public int? Property2 { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(3)]
  public int Property3 { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(4, DynamicType = true)]
  public object Property4 { get; set; }

  [ProtoMember(5, DynamicType = true)]
  public object Property5 { get; set; }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    A a = obj as A;
    if (a == null)
      return false;

    return a.Property1 == this.Property1
           && a.Property2 == this.Property2
           && a.Property3 == this.Property3
           && Object.Equals(a.Property4, this.Property4)
           && Object.Equals(a.Property5, this.Property5);
  }
}

public class B: A
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public string Property6 { get; set; }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    B b = obj as B;
    if (b == null)
      return false;

    return b.Property6 == this.Property6 && base.Equals(obj);
  }
}

[Test]
public void TestProtoBuf2()
{
  IList<A> list = new List<A>
                    {
                      new A {Property1 = 1, Property2 = 1, Property3 = 200, Property4 = "Test1", Property5 = DateTime.Now},
                      new B {Property1 = 2, Property2 = 2, Property3 = 400, Property4 = "Test2", Property5 = DateTime.Now, Property6 = "yyyy"},
                      new A {Property1 = 3, Property2 = 3, Property3 = 600, Property4 = "Test3", Property5 = new Decimal(200)},
                    };
  using (var file = new FileStream("list.bin", FileMode.Create))
  {
    Serializer.Serialize(file, list);
  }

  IList<A> list2;
  using (var file = File.OpenRead("list.bin"))
  {
    list2 = Serializer.Deserialize<IList<A>>(file);
  }

  Assert.AreEqual(list.Count, list2.Count);

  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
  {
    Assert.AreEqual(list[i], list2[i]);
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options) in BclHelpers.cs: line 444
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.NetObjectSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\NetObjectSerializer.cs: line 37
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TagDecorator.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\TagDecorator.cs: line 61
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.PropertyDecorator.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\PropertyDecorator.cs: line 53
at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in TypeSerializer.cs: line 200
at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs: line 418
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoReader reader, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Type type, ref Object value, Boolean skipOtherFields, Boolean asListItem, Boolean autoCreate, Boolean insideList) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs: line 895
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeList(ProtoReader reader, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Type listType, Type itemType, ref Object value) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs: line 712
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoReader reader, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Type type, ref Object value, Boolean skipOtherFields, Boolean asListItem, Boolean autoCreate, Boolean insideList) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs: line 851
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs: line 594
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs: line 518
at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs: line 500
at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(Stream source) in C:\Development\dotnet\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs: line 69
```

Comment: I dug out the code and it seems that the problem occurs because of the DateTime value which is a struct. Basically, in ReadNetObject, the DateTime value is initialized to the beginning of time, then its value changes after it gets deserialized, and the code thinks it changed the reference and it bombs out in BclHelper.cs at line 442.

Comment: from what I can see is that you are trying to use a "1 stop property" to contain all different data.

Is there anyway you can create a class with specific types rather than object and does it still continue?.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I have to do it this way for various reasons (save memory and it is makes coding simpler). I also specified that it is a dynamic type and I noticed that proto-buf puts the type info. I could create 3 members, ValueAsDecimal, ValueAsString and ValueAsDateTime but I don't want to do it.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Just a side question, to your knowledge, is v2 of protobuf-net used in production environments? thx

Comment: @costa yes,  many; including here at stackoverflow. I don't ask people to register application, but I know of many active v2 implemetations in industry, travel, medicine, games, and general business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re the field number; they need to be unique within a single type; it is not *required* that it is "max + 1" - they don't have to be contiguous - however, small numbers are preferable (as long as they are positive), as "varint" encoding can pack low field numbers (for headers) more efficiently.

Re the reference-tracking issue; this is a bug and is fixed in the current trunk - thanks; an edge case, but fixed.

Comment: @costa oh, you're pulling the trunk? that's fine - glad it worked

Comment: Yes. I will run my own tests as well to make sure that what I serialize I am getting back after deserialization.